# WKWebView doesn't load google docs in iframe

Tags: javascript, swift, iframe, wkwebview

I'm looking for solution for loading google docs in iframe using WKWebView.
This is my code and google docs sample

```
var webView: WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: self.configuration)
...
let htmlstring = "<!DOCTYPE html>         <html>         <body>          <iframe src=\"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeYZwAug7YgSvBs3ecMia_2GXkKgIgZIvNRRV2N-yLgm5ZC_A/viewform?embedded=true\" width=\"350\" height=\"500\"></iframe>          </body>         </html>"
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlstring, baseURL: nil)
```

But it show empty content.
Is there a solution to show google docs inside iframe ?

Comment: Have you tried the same thing in Safari? Does it work there? It might be that Google has framebuster JavaScript in their page source code.

Comment: yes, it works on Safari

Comment: now it works without changing any code. It seems google fix this issue.